# Diskpart can't delete partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, format, diskpart

My boot drive stopped booting with a registry issue, and now I cannot wipe the drive from a fresh windows image (on disk 1). 
I have tried to wipe the drive in many ways, and none of them work. I was able to read the data enough to get my data off, but I now have a "working drive" that I cannot touch. 
Is there a better way to wipe the drive, or is it dead and of the need for replacement? (The SSD is under warranty. I would just rather not deal with that)

This is what I get from diskpart:

I get the same issue for all partitions

```
    DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         2794 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          111 GB  1024 KB        *
* Disk 2    Online          238 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Recovery           450 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System              99 MB   451 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   550 MB
  Partition 4    Primary            237 GB   566 MB

DISKPART> delete partition

Virtual Disk Service error:
Cannot delete a protected partition without the force protected parameter set.


DISKPART> delete partition override

DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> delete disk

The disk you specified cannot be deleted.
Please select an empty missing disk to delete.

DISKPART> delete disk override

The disk you specified cannot be deleted.
Please select an empty missing disk to delete.
```

EDIT:
I tried GParted from a Debian boot drive. I tried deleting twice, once it errored, the second time said it was successful, then reloaded and nothing changed. Then I tried to reformat everything to NTFS, and this failed and when I canceled the format the drive stopped showing up. 
Now the drive does not show up in diskpart. I think it is time to contact the warranty.

Comment: Have you tried specifying each partition number for deletion?

Comment: I just tried. It brings up help/ says arguments are not valid.

Comment: Show SMART for the SSD, it sounds as if it's switched to read-only mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common cause for the behavior is the SSD failing or having switched to read-only mode to prevent full failure. SMART may reveal if this is the issue you're dealing with. For example this NVMe SSD switched to read-only:

[image]

In this example we see the RAW value for Critical Warning is 08 (hex), we [convert to binary](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-binary.html): 00001000

Bit meanings ([from](https://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/MKP_521.6_SMART-DCP1000_attribute.pdf)):

```
Bit 0: If set to ‘1’, then the available spare capacity has fallen below the threshold
Bit 1: If set to ‘1’, then a temperature is (> over temp threshold) or (< below temp threshold)
Bit 2: If set to ‘1’, then the NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded due to significant media related errors or any internal error that degrades NVM subsystemreliability.
Bit 3: If set to ‘1’, then the media has been placed in read only mode
Bit 4: If set to ‘1’, then the volatile memory backup device has failed. This field is only valid if the controller has a volatile memory backup solution.
```

So we have

```
7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Bit 3 is 'set', the drive is in read-only mode.

Comment: please explain downvote.

Comment: this is too old to remember the exact details and email search shows no results. I believe my warranty process showed that the drive had put itself in read-only from a hardware issue. so I got a new drive.

Comment: doesn't mean you have to downvote the answer. remember we write answers for future users too. and by what you remember, the answer is actually correct, the drive was in read-only mode.

Comment: Not my down-vote, I don't have the rep to vote. I only hesitate to mark as the answer because the knowledge of read only wouldn't have solve my original issue

Comment: Ahh, I see. No problem then.

Comment: After seeing others online with similar issues, I will mark this as solution. I now remember that Windows wouldn't boot off a read only drive, so I am more confident in my memory. Though in the case of my ASX6000NP it took an RMA to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [GParted](https://gparted.org/) and create a bootable flash drive from the ISO using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

[image]

2. Reboot your computer and select your flash drive as the boot drive.
3. Once GParted has loaded, delete the partition in question from within the GUI and apply your changes.

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not work. I will put details at the bottom of the question

Comment: Before you go the warranty route, I would try backing up the data than performing an ATA Secure Erase to nuke everything on it using hdparm. You can initiate that from within GParted by running a command in Terminal. If nothing else, it would at least be interesting to see if *that* could remove the problematic partition. https://techgage.com/article/securely-erasing-your-ssd-with-linux-a-how-to/